# How can i delete array of file object with file systeme node js after delete user

Tags: node.js

i can't delte array of file from node js
my code is this :
[image]

when i add a new artiste this is what i get in mongodb:
[image]

and when i get artiste :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `fs.unlinkSync` method inside the loop.

```
if(artiste.photo) {
   artiste.photo.forEach(function(photo){
     fs.unlinkSync("public/images/"+ photo.filename);
   })
}
```

Comment: i unterstand what you mean..but is not this the problem..in mongo db i save the fileName but i use mapper to get tow files(one file is a full image and anothor is a thumbnail image ,save in the public/images..you can see them when i get request ) so i need to delete the image from mongodb(use fileName) and from public/images(there are 2 file name one full and another thumbnel)